# integral with bessel function represented as a series

Tags: integration, special-functions, approximation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prove equality with integral and series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159180/prove-equality-with-integral-and-series)

This integral was my homework question with $p=2$ and $n=1$. I am wondering if one can get the general formula for p, or at least approximate this integral for any $p$, $n=1$?
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2^n}{t^n}\left(\frac{t^n}{2^nn!}-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\frac{t^{n+2}}{1!(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{2^{n+4}}\frac{t^{n+4}}{2!(n+2)!}-\ldots\right)\right)^ptdt
$$

Thank you.

Comment: This already have been asked, but I can't find that answer...

Comment: @Norbert Above is the link to the duplicate.

Comment: @MArvis, thanks. This question must be closed.

Comment: it is a generalization for $p>2$ of the question linked.